# User interface element for 3-way input: yes, no, don't care

Tags: user-interface, user-controls, user-input

I'm looking for a nice, compact user interface for input of a ternary value: true, false and don't case. It might be used, for example, in a grid view for filtering a column that displays a binary value: don't care shows all records, true filters for rows with the property, and false filters for those without.

I was considering something like an empty ballot box ☐ for don't care, check mark ✔ true, and ballot X ✘ for false. When the user clicks on the control it cycles to the next.

I think this would work for anglo-saxons but I'm not sure check marks and Xs are understood the same in other places.

Comment: Could be worth trying User Experience at http://ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: We understand it in Central Europe, too, if the ballot is red and check mark green. You are true that some people could misunderstand the ballot as "yes" if not coloured.

Comment: Desktop application or web application?

Comment: I will be doing it on the web but a control that's seen in both environments would be best.

Comment: duplicate: https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107996/boolean-switch-with-a-third-state

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you're looking for a [tri-state checkbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Checkbox#Tri-state_checkbox)?

[image: Wikipedia image of tri-state checkbox]

The third state is generally used for values such as "don't care", "indeterminate", "both", "neither", and so on.

Comment: Unfortunately, that checkbox doesn't make clear which states, either unchecked or indeterminate, mean "no" and "don't care".

Comment: I disagree. Anyone who's used a regular checkbox probably understands that "checked" = "yes" and "unchecked" = "no". If the indeterminate state of "don't care" is the default, displaying all rows, then it should be pretty easy to intuit.

Comment: This is just the right user control for the job. It is not as well known or well understood as some other inputs but you do see it around, like in a tree of checkboxes.

Comment: My problem now is to find the most elegant way to implement it in HTML with unobtrusive javascript.

Answer (score 2):

I would advocate for just two radio buttons: "True" and "False". If neither one of them is checked then the third option, "Don't care" is implicit. However, users will sometimes want to go back to "Don't care" once they've already selected a choice. You could have the a small button to clear their choice, or have it clear if they click again on the choice that is already selected.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but it sounds like your asking for an exclusive choice input option (You can only choose 1 of the 3 options). If this is the case, you really want the radio-button input type.  It prevents you from selecting more than one option at a time and can be used to require a choice. You can group the buttons into multiple collections and scramble them if you like.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_radio is an example of the radio button option

Comment: While I normally disagree with posting links to w3schools, I want to point out that their tryit is quite nice.  It lets you do pretty much anything.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a combo box which shows a blank string or the words "Don't care" by default.
  The other two options would be "Yes" and "No".